# custom backspace button crashes iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I have a custom keyboard and whenever I touch the backspace button for the first time my app crashes! How can I solve this problem?

My code:

```
 myText.text = [myText.text substringToIndex:([myText.text length]-1)];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test if the existing text has at least one character for you to trim out...

```
if ([myText.text length]>0) myText.text = [myText.text substringToIndex:([myText.text length]-1)];
```

Comment: then how do you trim the last character?

Comment: The last character is naturally taken care of here. When the size of the text is 1, the code shown will simply decrement it to 0...